# Why are there curved propellers?

Tags: propeller, engine-design

[image]

Why are there curved propellers on some aircraft, what is there advantage?

If these are worthwhile advantages why aren't there curved blades on turbo fans?

Comment: @Pondlife my main question is could they be used in fans

Comment: [why aren't there curved blades on turbo fans?](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eoNySabChvA/maxresdefault.jpg)

Comment: Some jet engines do have curved blades. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_GE90#/media/File:GE90_B777-200LR.JPG